Is the PLONK paper incorrect?
I'm having some confuses while implementing the PLONK by following the instruction in the Plonk paper. Could someone please help me with it?
In step 6th of the "Verifier preprocessed input" phase, we have the formula as in the first screenshot, but when I use it, I couldn't make the code pass. Then I took a look at this article https://hackmd.io/@chaosma/ByBIElFno#Verify-Preprocessing then tried to change my code according to their formula to compute the L1, as in the second screenshot, and it worked (also look at several implementations and in all of them $w = 1$. So my question is: Is the formula written in the paper incorrect or am I missing something?
Paper link: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf
Note: My question is essentially about why $w = 1$.



The latter is a special case where ω = 1; what did you use for its value?

I just follow the instructions in this https://hackmd.io/@chaosma/ByBIElFno#Verify-Preprocessing

It turned out that the paper was updated while I was implementing the protocol. The author changed some mathematics in it, thus leading to the discrepancy as stated above

This is not a duplicate question :(

If you want this to be reopened, please [edit] it to explain why it is different from the current duplicate.
